# Fill divs with content from hidden directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, transfer

I have a hidden directory (.directory) with several divs (.content) and different content in it.

Now on pageload, I want to randomly pick a div (.content) from the directory and place it in the lower, visible divs (.box).

The hidden directory has more divs (.content) than should be shown at the end in the visible divs (.box). For example, I have 20 hidden content divs, but just randomly 3 should be shown.

So my solution would be, that JS counts on pageload, how much divs named ".box" and then randomly pick the counted amount of divs named ".content" from the directory and place in the divs named ".box". Would that be the right way?

But I really have no idea, how to do that :D

I have prepared a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m5sqwrpg/4/

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="directory">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline A</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline B</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline C</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline D</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline E</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline F</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.directory {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that should get you started:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".box").each(function(){
       var contentDivs = $(".directory .content");
       var contentToPick = Math.floor(Math.random()*(contentDivs.length));
       $(contentDivs[contentToPick]).appendTo($(this));
    });
});
```

```css
.directory {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="directory">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline A</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline B</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline C</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline D</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline E</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline F</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

I don't guarantee it will work the way you envision, so it will be good to give it a proper test.

It should basically pull a random div from the ".directory" div for each ".box".
It relies on the fact, that when we select a div from ".directory" we actually remove it from ".directory" to put it in ".box" so even if the random function returns the same index, on the second pass, the div there will be different.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT : @Pavel Donchev solution is better :)**

It's better for you to change the CSS style of your elements to display them, or not.

To choose a define number of random elements, you can do it like this :

```js
function randomContent(numberOfElements){
  var i = 0; 
  var randomElements = $(".content").get().sort(function() {
        return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
     }).slice(0, numberOfElements);
      
      
   while(i < randomElements.length) {
       if($(randomElements[i]).hasClass('show')){
        break;
      }
      else{
        $(randomElements[i]).addClass('show');
        i++;
      }
  }
}

randomContent(3);
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.show{
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="directory">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline A</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline B</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline C</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline D</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline E</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="headline">Headline F</div>
    <div class="text">Some kind of Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Working JSFiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/2m9tdgn2/

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :).However if my solution is triggered by let's say a button - you will pretty much run out of divs in 3-4 clicks :).

Answer (score 0):

Hi as per undersanding below code will solve your problem easily just put that code under script tag. also include jquery.min.js in your html. to avoide $ is undefined :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    drawRandomDivContent();
});
function drawRandomDivContent()
{
var container=$(".content");
var array=[];
var dataarray=[]
for(var i=0;i<container.length;i++)
{
   var number=getRandomInt(container.length);
   if($.inArray(number,array)==-1)
   {
        var selectedDiv=container[number];
        dataarray.push(selectedDiv);
        array.push(number);
        if(array.length==3)
        break;
   }
}
var destinationdiv=$(".box");
for(var i=0;i<dataarray.length;i++)
destinationdiv[i].innerHTML=dataarray[i].innerHTML;
}
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
```